# quero passa a minha função java script para o bean ao carregar a pagina

Tags: javascript, java, jsf-2.2, xhtml, primefaces-5.2

quero passa a minha função java script para o bean ao carregar a pagina, sem precisar do click do botão ? estou usando o remotCommand do primeface, `onPoint([{name:'latitude',value:latitude},{name:'longitude',value:longitude}]);`

Comment: Olá fabio, lendo oa sua pergunta não está muito claro o que você está tentando fazer e que problema você está tendo. Comece escrevendo um exemplo de código que isole o seu problema (leia mais sobre [MVCEs](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), depois completemente sua pergunta com todas as informações que você precisaria para entender seu problema se fosse um desenvolvedor sem nenhum conhecimento ou acesso ao sistema (caso de quem responderá a pergunta). Com essas informações edite sua pergunta e sua chance de obter uma resposta aumentarão consideravelmente.

Comment: Creio que você esteja querendo passar parâmetros para um remoteCommand a partir de um Javascript. Se entendi corretamente, revise sua pergunta que eu respondo com um exemplo funcional.